# Number of Minimally Functionally Complete (adequate) ternary Operators Sets and what they are

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is there a simpler way than through trial and error to determine the number of Minimally Functionally Complete Operator Sets (MFCOS) (or adequate operator sets) for a given arity and what those operator sets are? According to wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness) there are 26 MFCOS for arity-2.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm almost certain the answer is "no", but how to prove that it is "no"...

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem in “Computer Science and Multiple-Valued Logic” by North-Holland does provide a rigorous theorem on page 161 which I will cite here. That chapter can be found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=IwbjBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=ivo%20g.%20rosenberg,%20%22completeness%20properties%20of%20multiple-valued%20logic%20algebras%22&source=bl&ots=3sZrXDINtY&sig=E1YcqdKjFNxK_F6nw6EsrycnWxQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie1p64l6bRAhXC4CYKHb-XDkQQ6AEIITAC#v=onepage&q=ivo%20g.%20rosenberg%2C%20%22completeness%20properties%20of%20multiple-valued%20logic%20algebras%22&f=false)

**3.11 Theorem.** *Each maximal class in $O_k$ is of the form Pol $\rho$ where $\rho$ is one of the following relations on k:*

1. Every partial order on k with a least and greatest element.
2. Every relation $\{<x,sx>|x\in k\}$ where s is a permutation of k with k/p
   cycles of the same prime length p.
3. Every quaternary relation
   $\{<a_0, …, a_3>\in k^4|a_0+’ a_1 = a_2 +’ a_3\}$ where $<k,+’>$ is a
   p-elementary abelian group (p prime).
4. Every non-trivial
   equivalence relation on k.
5. Every central relation on k.
6. Every relation $\lambda_T$ determined by an h-regular family $T$ of
   equivalence relations on k (h>2).

A set is complete if and only if for every relation described under 1.-6. above there exists an $f \in X$ not preserving $\rho$.